# Entityframework : DropCreateDatabaseAlways, where and how?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am working with Entityframework Code-First and trying to get my tables to drop and then recreate at every startup. However Database.SetInitializer is not recognized and intellisense is not giving me a using directive. Hovering over setinitializer gives the following information:

> > DatabaseFacade does not contain a definition for 'setinitializer'....

And my Applicationdbcontext below.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways());

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

      //dbsets
}
```

}

Am i implementing 'Database.SetInitializer' in the wrong place? Why am i not getting any using directive information from intellisense?

Comment: EF6 or EF Core? EF Core does not have initializers.

Comment: Aha! EF Core. That explains alot! Thanks Steve. Do you know what i should look in to / be using instead?

Comment: See the section on initialization [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) - half way down. Basically, use `ensurecreated`. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355481/auto-create-database-in-entity-framework-core)