# DbUpdateException error trying to use EF core code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Web API and I am trying to use entity framework core code first, with an external sql server database hosted on AWS RDS. My aim is for EF to create my model database/tables automatically, based on my context and models,  the first time I use Swagger to create an object. Although when I try to post an object to my API with Swagger, tables do not get created and instead I get the following error: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Users'.`

Did I set up EF incorrectly?

Db Context:

```
namespace FitnessTrackerAPI.Data
{
    public class FitnessTrackerAPIContext : DbContext
    {
        public FitnessTrackerAPIContext (DbContextOptions<FitnessTrackerAPIContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<FitnessTracker.UserData> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<FitnessTracker.WorkoutData> Workouts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also added the following to Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddDbContext<FitnessTrackerAPIContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FitnessTrackerAPIContext")));
         ....

    private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
         using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
         {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FitnessTrackerAPIContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
         }
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //Apply pending migrations
        InitializeDatabase(app);
        ....
```

Connection String in appsettings.json: `"ConnectionStrings": {
    "FitnessTrackerAPIContext": "Server=fitnessapi.clxnbxbuoxx1.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX; Initial Catalog=fitnessapi; Database=fitnessapi; Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"`

Comment: Is `InitializeDatabase()` being called?

Comment: @mxmissile Yes its the last line of code above ^ in Startup.cs. I call it in the Configure method `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //Apply pending migrations
        InitializeDatabase(app);`

Comment: Sorry, I meant is it actually being executed at runtime?

Comment: Setting a breakpoint, or logging would tell you.

Comment: looks like it runs fine: https://imgur.com/a/Edkd6yL

Comment: does the `Invalid object name 'Users'.` error suggest that it cannot find the context file? `public DbSet<FitnessTracker.UserData> Users { get; set; }`

Comment: Next question would be are the tables actually getting created? Check using SSMS.

Comment: No Users or Workouts tables, but there is an _EFMigrationsHistory table

Comment: Try calling  `context.Database.EnsureCreated();`, I'm not an EF pro, you'll want to read up on this method, cause I think you should only call that once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355481

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy

Comment: Did that method work?

Comment: It sure did, thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` to "ensure" the tables are created. More about this [method here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-3.1).