# SqlException: Cannot open database X requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user Y

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have searched high and low for a fix for this and cannot find one that works in my case. I've setup a new project using Razor Pages with no authentication.

Made a change to a model, so added a migration and when trying to update the database, it wouldn't let me as it always returned an error saying it was read only.

So, I used SSOX to delete the database and now when running my app, I get the said error. Its almost as if it's not initialising properly?

```
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, bool result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
IUKApplicantManager.Pages.Applicants.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in Index.cshtml.cs
+
            Applicant = await applicants.ToListAsync();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: are the login details correct? is it using trusted auth, or cn/pw?

Comment: You will get that error if the database you're trying to connect to does not exist. What in your application is responsible for actually creating a brand new database?

Comment: @mason perhaps this is where my knowledge is limited. I have a Data folder which contains the database context. Then, in my Startup.cs file, I have a ConfigureServices() method which adds this database context.

Comment: @MarcGravell I never configured any user accounts, so as far as I'm aware, this shouldn't be the issue?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355481/auto-create-database-in-entity-framework-core) explains multiple ways to ensure that your database gets created with EF Core.

Comment: @mason I think I might have figured the issue out. For some reason, my default database creation location is in the root of my C drive, which I won't have permission to write to on this machine. Do you know how I would change this location? I have right-clicked and looked at properties on the server, then looked at the default database location, but this doesn't actually match where the database is being created.

Comment: You cannot change the database path , please refer to: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3101
. A better solution is that you can get the permissions of the C drive.