# Auto Create database using EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core in my Winforms application but I can't generate database automatically without migrations.

I read this articles but It is for asp.net core: [auto create database in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355481/auto-create-database-in-entity-framework-core)

My `DbContext`:

```
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Accounts> Acc { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FreeAcc"].ConnectionString);
    }
```

Edit: I'm using localdb

Comment: You do **need** Migrations to generate the Db automatically. Otherwise you need to create the schema yourself.

Comment: You could try using `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created#ensurecreated)

Comment: @Shoejep I didn't know about those APIs and been having some experience in EF Core recently. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` to create the database if it doesn't exist.

> EnsureCreated will create the database if it doesn't exist and initialize the database schema. If any tables exist (including tables for another DbContext class), the schema won't be initialized.

`EnsureCreated` is part of EF Core in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, it's not exclusive to ASP.NET Core.

I suggest you call `EnsureCreated` when your application starts up or just before you use your `DbContext`.

[EF Core Create and Drop APIs Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created#ensurecreated)