# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : update database command on deployment

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to ASP.NET Core and using Entity Framework 6.

I have created a Web API using MySql. On development, I have executed add migrations and `update-database` command.

Now, I have published the Web API and I have to deploy it on a server. The server doesn't have development environment. I want to update the production database. How can I do this?`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this : "The server doesn't have development environment."

You only have to replace Database ConnectionString of your project with ConnectionString of server, and then use `update-database` to update database.

Comment: I execute this command from Visual Studio PM Console. But the server doesn't has visual studio. Then how to execute this command.

Comment: have you change the connection string?

Server Doesn't need to has visual studio

Comment: Yes, I have changed connection string. Deployed published code on IIS. But database server doesn't have new changes. It means I have to execute update - database command.

Comment: Do you get error or something?

Comment: I Think this helps

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356110/10786639 , 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63638589/10786639