# Why AppDbContext constructor is not invoked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, database-connection, dbcontext

I am writing an api using aspnet identity, on configuring services I use .AddDbContext methdos but nothing happens. The construcotr of AppDBContext is not invoked. I set a breakpoint in AppDBContext to ckeck if it is called but constructor is not invoked.
Here is my dbcontext

```
public class AppDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions<AppDBContext> options) : base (options)
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
}
```

And Program.cs with configuration

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// For Entity Framework
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

#region AUTHENTICATION
// For Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Adding Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    // Adding Jwt Bearer
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
        };
    });
#endregion

#region REPOSITORIES
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
#endregion

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

#region SERVICES
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthService, AuthService>();
#endregion

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

PS:connectionString is right(checked in debug)

Comment: Where you use ``IAuthRepository``?

Comment: DbContext is only created when you use it in a controller for example, registering it will not create an instance. you can use the following: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356110/5632166)

Comment: thank you, now i understand how it works