# C# - Entity Framework Core - auto create database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework-core, desktop-application

I want to automatically create the database and table structures when my desktop app is first run.
I can't find any examples or documentation on something equivalent for EFCore.

I did everything as it is in this documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html

But I still have a problem: Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll, and empty database :( Please help me, if you can.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            try
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;userid=root;password=topSecret;database=kartoteka-pracownicza");               
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: In the link provided the database is created with context.Database.[EnsureCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-6.0) seems that will do what you want.

Comment: Hello Check this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355481/auto-create-database-in-entity-framework-core
Good luck

Comment: EnsureCreated will work but it is not compatible with migrations, so make sure you don't want to use migrations before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can add to something like this in your `Startup.cs` if you using `Migrations`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
         using (var serviceScope = 
         app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
         {
               var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
               context.Database.Migrate();
         }
    }
```

If you are not using Migrations you can change `Migrate();`
with `EnsureCreated();` for using your DB context