# How to fix table does not exist Entity Framework Core with SQLite 7.0 code-first

Tags: entity-framework-core

Exception in EF Core 7 / SQLite with a code-first approach :

> Table does not exist

Code is here with issue detail:

https://github.com/HumairaSid/EFCoreBasicCaching

I'm trying to create a SQLite database with Entity Framework Core 7.0 and a code-first approach.

Issue is table does not exist, it seems actual problem is database is not getting created by code.

I need your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto create database on first run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355481/how-to-auto-create-database-on-first-run)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using

// Drop the database if it exists

```
 dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created
I have added to my startup file