# EF create table without migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to create a table in code. The problem is, that I'm not allowed to use migrations. Application should check on start, whether the tables exist and add them on demand.

I have a very basic implementation of `DbContext` which is created by calling this method:

```
    public static ConfigurationDbContext CreateRemoteContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        var context = new ConfigurationDbContext(nameOrConnectionString);

        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        return context;
    }
```

And a configuration container, which gets passed to the rest parts of the application. It contains arrays for every table, that get loaded like this:

```
    using (var dbContext = ConfigurationDbContext.CreateRemoteContext(App.Database.DbConnectionName))
    {
        var result = new ConfigurationContainer
        {
            ExistingTableEntities = dbContext.ExistingEntities.ToArray(),
            ...
            NotExistingTableEntities = dbContext.NotExistingTableEntities.ToArray()
        };
        ...
    }
```

Here all of the entities get loaded to the configuration container. While trying to access a not existing table, is predictably throws an exception.

How can I check, whether the table exists and create it on demand without migration?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use migrations because you have an existing database that isn't managed by EF?   If that's the case, I would recommend using upgrade SQL scripts with the required steps and then using `_context.Database.ExecuteSQL` to run the scripts..

Comment: What do you mean by that you can't use migrations?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45795873/11350283

Comment: @Neil yep, that's appropriate in my case. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @devcrp this looks nice, but is for EF Core.

Comment: Code-first's main driver is to simplify database development by having the computer _do all the heavy lifting_. i.e. taking care of the schema so you don't have to.  To not use EF Migrations and do so manually via code arguably defeats the purpose of code-first.  Perhaps you should consider using _Data Tier Applications; SSDT projects_ and _deployment via DACPACs_.  DACPACs require zero coding and can do many things EF Migrations can't do easily. Staged deployments comes to mind